# Angular Typescript cookie exists logic

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm utilizing the "ngx-cookie-service" to work with cookies in my angular project.

I have sumpled across an issue where I check if a cookie exists, if it === false then it should retrieve data from an API, but on the first run it always returns false due to the cookie not existing, but the `JSON` is not retrieved as seen in this picture.
[image]

After another reload it then shows that the cookie exists and retrieves the data successfully as seen in this image.

[image]

I'm very confused why it doesn't print the `JSON` in the first request, but does it in any request following.

Here is my typescript code.

```
let cookieExists: boolean = this.cookieService.check(this.id);

console.log("Cookie exists: " + cookieExists);

if (cookieExists === false) {
  axios.get('https://localhost:5001/api/Trace/' + this.id)
    .then((response: AxiosResponse<Trace>) => {
      var minutesToAdd = 1;
      var currentDate = new Date();
      var futureDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + minutesToAdd * 60000);

      this.cookieService.set(this.id, JSON.stringify(response.data), futureDate, null, null, null, null);
    });
}

console.log(this.cookieService.get(this.id));
```

Upon the initial request, the data should be printed in the console, just like in the second image.

Async code that I have tried, with the same result.

```
let cookieExists: boolean = this.cookieService.check(this.id);

console.log("Cookie exists: " + cookieExists);

if (cookieExists === false) {
  const doGetRequest = async () => {
    await axios.get('https://localhost:5001/api/Trace/' + this.id)
      .then((response: AxiosResponse<Trace>) => {
        var minutesToAdd = 1;
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var futureDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + minutesToAdd * 60000);

        this.cookieService.set(this.id, JSON.stringify(response.data), futureDate, null, null, null, null);
      });
  };
  doGetRequest();
}

console.log(this.cookieService.get(this.id));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Comment: I tried doing it inside a async () {} with await before axios.get, but with the same result.

Comment: `"I tried doing it inside a async () {} with await before..."` ← Please update the code in your question with your latest attempt. Please also show all the relevant code including the method signature and how it is called.

Comment: What I have tried is what I just said. I wrapped the get request with async () => {} and put await in front of axios.get. Same result.

Comment: If you want to get help, you should update the code in your question with your latest attempt.

Comment: I added the updated code, hopefully someone can spot what I'm doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by taking the get request related code into a new function that is Async instead of inside the constructor with Async inline function.

```
constructor(...) {
  this.doWork();
}

async doWork() {
  ...

  let cookieExists: boolean = this.cookieService.check(this.id);

  if (cookieExists === false) {
    await axios.get('https://localhost:5001/api/Trace/' + this.id)
      .then((response: AxiosResponse<Trace>) => {
        var minutesToAdd = 5;
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var futureDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + minutesToAdd * 60000);

        this.cookieService.set(this.id, JSON.stringify(response.data), futureDate, null, null, null, null);
      });
  }

  let json: string = this.cookieService.get(this.id);
  this.trace = JSON.parse(json);
  
  ...
}
```